# Unsupported depth in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to learn some basics, but I keep getting errors.

I am trying to resize a cv::Mat

Edit to clarify why I am not loading an image: I am trying to test without having access to external files.

Inside the code, though, I put `int x = M.depth();` and it read 0

```
cv::Mat M(2,2, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
scale = 2;
cv::Size myImageSize;
myImageSize.height = M.rows;
myImageSize.width  = M.cols;

cv::Mat ImgCopy = cvCreateImage(myImageSize, M.depth(), M.channels());
..
cv::resize(M, ImgCopy, myImageSize, 0, 0, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
```

I am getting an error on the line cvCreateImage

```
Input image depth is not supported by function (Unsupported format) in unknown functio, file... \modules\core\src\array.cpp...
```

I have tried with other values (CV_32F...) and I get the same error.

Please help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cvCreateImage()` is for use with the C API and returns an `IplImage*`. To initialize a `cv::Mat`, use the appropriate constructor.

```
cv::Mat ImgCopy(M.size(), M.type());
```

is the most succinct way to create and allocate memory for a new `cv::Mat`.

However, `cv::resize()` makes it even easier. You just have to declare your image

```
cv::Mat ImgCopy
```

and the arguments to `cv::resize()` allow automatic calculation of the correct dimensions and type. The last three parameters do not need to be specified because you don't change them from the defaults.

```
cv::resize(M, ImgCopy, myImageSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
 {
IplImage *src,*dst;
src=cvLoadImage("img.png");
cvNamedWindow("SRC", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvNamedWindow("DST", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);


 dst = cvCreateImage(cvSize(500,500),src->depth,src->nChannels);
cvResize(src,dst);


cvShowImage("SRC",src);
cvShowImage("DST",dst);


cvWaitKey(0);
cvDestroyWindow("SRC");
cvDestroyWindow("DST");
cvReleaseImage(&dst);
cvReleaseImage(&src);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't load an image, I am trying to test without having access to external resources, that is why I am trying to manufacture a cv::Mat